# PHP pagination of 400+ pictures

Tags: php

a have a website with more than 400 pictures in a directory. I'd like to list them by 12 on every page. How can i do that? Here is my actual code:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="hu">
    <head>
        <title>Amatőr</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2><a href="../php/upload_picture.php" style="font-size:15pt; color:#ff00e8; text-decoration: none;">Vannak jó képeid? Töltsd fel őket és kikerülhetnek az oldalra!</a></h2>
        <article>
            <header>
                Amatőr Lányok
            </header>
            <div id="kepek">
                <?php
                $imgdir = '../img/blog/img/amator/'; //Pick your folder
                $allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif'); //Allowed types of files
                $dimg = opendir($imgdir);//Open directory
                while($imgfile = readdir($dimg))
                {
                  if( in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-3)),$allowed_types) OR
                      in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-4)),$allowed_types) )
                /*If the file is an image add it to the array*/
                  {$a_img[] = $imgfile;}
                }


                 $totimg = count($a_img);  //The total count of all the images
                //Echo out the images and their paths incased in an li.
                 for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){ echo "<a onclick='Lightbox.start(this, false, false, false, false); return false;' rel='lightbox[amator]' href='" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "'><img class='kep_listaz' width='200px' height='160px' src='" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' /></a>";}
                ?>
            </div>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>

Thanks!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is really more of a maths questions.
You will need to get the total count of the images, then divide that by the max number of images per page (make sure to [`ceil()`](http://php.net/ceil) it).

You have now a max number of pages needed to view all of these images. What you need to do now is figure whether you want page=1/page=2 etc or as a start and end. Both are relatively easy, however, with the page you'd need to do

```
$page = (int)$_GET['page'];
$start = $page * $max_items_per_page;
$end = $start + $max_items_per_page;
```

This way it's probably saver. Also add extra code to make sure you're not out of bounds with the page requested.

Now it's a matter of getting an array of the files (I suggest you use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob)) and use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) that from start to end.

Finally just have a previous/next page, or list all (or some) of the pages. Getting next and previous is as simple as adding/removing 1 to `$page`, i.e. `$next = $page + 1;` and `$prev = $page-1;`. Again, for both of these, double check that you're not out of bounds. Probably best not to show next/previous if they are out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to paginate this kind of data: on the front-end where you send it all and JavaSctipt only shows the user a portion at a time, or on the back-end where the page is only rendered with a portion at a time and you reload the whole page to get more.

The fastest way to get it working is using the back-end method:

Before your for loop add `$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page']-1 : 0;`

Change the loop's argument to  `$x=$page*12; $x < $totimg && $x < ($page+1)*12; $x++`

Then you can manipulate pages by adding `?page=3` to the url

You'll also want to add some error handling incase an invalid page number is submitted.

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem is, that this page is handed to the browser via ajax, so the url doesn't really change. How do I add the ?page=x this way?

Comment: There's no reason you can't change the url for the ajax call, or you can send the param as data if the ajax is a post.

Comment: Here is my current ajax call: http://pastebin.com/BFvyS1jF   .. Did i do it right? I Added ?page=1 at the end of the url. Also how do i add the page navigations on the ajaxed content below the images? Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll find the ajax much easier if you use jQuery or another library that gives you easy syntax and guarantees cross-browser compatibility. For the page links, just use a for loop like `for($page=1; ($page-1)*12 < $totimg; $page++){ echo "<a href="?page=$page">$page</a>" }`

Comment: Thanks a lot! The pages work, it displays it correctly, the only problem is, when i click on another page it brings me back to the non-ajaxed page. Let me explain: I have blog.php, where i have 3 categories. Each category brings up another category selection (ex:for images) via ajax, then when you choose your next caregory (here it's 'amator') it brings it up again in ajax. So when i click the page number, it brings me back to blog.php without any ajax loaded.